# Upvoted challenge but no answer

Tags: support, specific-question

I'm confused by my question [Fix the Meeesesessessesseesseessedessed upp teeexexextext](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62200/fix-the-meeesesessessesseesseessedessed-upp-teeexexextext). I get 7 upvotes but no answer. It is well defined, too, as Martin Buettner has fixed it during sandboxing. What's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your question. [There are questions with a lot more upvotes which haven't received answers in months or years](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/unanswered). Your challenge has only been up for a few days, and due to the requirement for optimality it's moderately difficult. Sometimes it can take a while for answers to come in, and sometimes you'll only get one or two.

Just keep writing challenges. Some of them will be more and some will be less popular, but the more experience you get, the more you'll be able to gauge up front how much fun a challenge will be.